Do anaerobic organisms that have a terminal electron acceptor other than oxygen have a Citric Acid cycle?
I have been teaching for a while (College level) and realize that I need to make sure I'm accurate as students get more savvy, and more information is published. I teach that anaerobic respiration and fermentation are different. In fermentation the NAD+ are re-generated and Glycolysis can go ~16x faster. But when I talk about anaerobic respiration I say that the process is the "same" as aerobic respiration just a different electron acceptor. But I admit I don't know much more than that, and as I do research, for example into sulfur-reducing bacteria, I am not finding clear information.
I've been assuming that strict anaerobes don't just rely on fermentation and utilize an Electron transport chain, ETC to generate ATP. But do they use a cycle like the Citric Acid cycle? In other words can they fully oxidize glucose/pyruvate/acetyl-CoA?
If they don't fully oxidize glucose and/or pyruvate, what are the consequences of building up pyruvate (biochemically)?
If they don't fully oxidize glucose, how do they produce enough electron carriers (NADH, FADH2) to make enough ATP in their ETC? Or do they just require less ATP per glucose to survive?
Sorry if there are false assumptions in this question, I really want to understand and make sure I'm giving out accurate info.

I have revised your title so that it describes your concern more precisely, and avoids the rather unfortunate phrase "alternative electron acceptor" (not "alternate") which in plain English implies (wrongly) that the organism has alternatives. Unfortunately this whole field is riddled with unfortunate but accepted nomenclature. Please read my answer carefully and let me know whether you require clarification. It is difficult to find details of the metabolism of these organisms in text books, because of their complexity and difficulty of study.

Terminology

“I teach that anaerobic respiration and fermentation are different.”

Although not conforming to the historic or lay use of the terms “respiration” and “fermentation” the poster is correct regarding the current scientific usage of these terms, as evidenced by the following quotations from the Wikipedia article on fermentation:

“The definition of fermentation has evolved over the years. The most
modern definition is catabolism where organic compounds are both the
electron donor and acceptor. A common electron donor is glucose, and
pyruvate is a common electron acceptor. This definition distinguishes
fermentation from aerobic respiration, where oxygen is the acceptor,
and types of anaerobic respiration where inorganic compound is the
acceptor.”

This is developed in more detail in the Wikipedia article on Anaerobic respiration.
However, given the confusing nature of the terminology, if I were teaching this myself I would  first stress the fundamental difference between the two ways of converting metabolic ‘energy’ to ATP: 1. Directly phosphorylating ADP in a metabolic reaction, and 2. Establishing an electrochemical gradient across a membrane that drives the multi-subunit ATP synthase that produces ATP from ADP and inorganic phosphate. Indeed, depending on the background of one’s students, the use of the word “oxidation” to “mean removal of electrons” may need emphasizing.
N.B. The regeneration of NADH+ in fermentation is to allow the process to continue at all, not to accelerate 16x or by any other factor as stated in the question.
Necessity of  the Tricarboxylic Acid Cycle for Anaerobic Respiration

“Do anaerobic organisms that have a terminal electron acceptor other
than oxygen have a Citric Acid cycle?”

No, not necessarily. Some may, but others only have genes for some of the enzymes of the tricarboxylic acid cycle, as a genomic analysis by Huynen et al. demonstrated (relevant details in footnote).

I say that the process is the “same“ as aerobic respiration just a
different electron acceptor.

No, that is incorrect. Certainly a system analagous to the mitochondrial electron transport system must be present to establish an electrochemical gradient. However the assumption that the process is the same in other respects and  “glucose/pyruvate/acetyl-CoA” must be involved and provide the electrons through generation of NADH in the tricarboxylic acid cycle is unfounded. Bacteria that utilize ‘unusual’ terminal electron acceptors generally occupy ‘unusual’ ecological niches, with ‘unusual’ sources of carbon and reducing power.
An example: bacteria of the Desulfovibrio genus
I found it difficult to find detailed metabolic information about bacteria which employ terminal electron acceptor other than oxygen. This may reflect the fact that many occupy extreme ecological niches and are difficult to study in the laboratory. In addition the situation is often confused by alternative methods of oxidation (some are also fermenters) and the possibility of symbiotic relationships with other bacteria). One more tractible example is found in members of the Desulfovibrio genus, which employ sulphate as their terminal electron acceptor, and use hydrogen and various organic acids as the source of reductive energy. With metabolic observations supplemented by genomic and transcriptomic analysis the model below has been proposed for the flow of electrons during sulphate respiration in D. vulgaris.

From a 2011 review by Keller and Wall which should be consulted for further details.
It should be emphasized that the pyruvate generated when lactate is oxidized is converted to acetate as an end-product and not converted into acetyl-CoA for input into a tricarboxylic acid cycle. Genome sequencing indicates that genes for most of the enzymes of the cycle are present, except for citrate synthase and perhaps 2-ketoglutarate dehydrogenase. It should be explained that the presence of an incomplete tricarboxylic acid cycle allows other metabolic interconversions to occur, and, to quote Huynen et al.,

“it has been argued that the CAC evolved originally as two separate
pathways stemming from pyruvate, with an oxidative branch leading to
2-ketoglutarate and a reductive branch leading to succinyl CoA
[Melendez-Hevia, E., Wadell, T.G. and Cascante, M. (1996) J. Mol.
Evol. 43, 293–303]”.

Footnote: Hynen et al. and incomplete tricarboxylic acid cycles
At least one of the bacteria the genome of which Hynen et al. found to lack enzymes of the tricarboxylic acid cycle — Methanocaldococcus jannaschii — uses an alternative electron acceptor. It is only capable of growth on carbon dioxide and hydrogen as an energy source, and lacks genes for the first three enzymes of the oxidative cycle: citrate synthase, iconitase and isocitrate dehydrogenase. A detailed consideration of the energetics of such methanogens can be found in a review by Thauer et al..

There are a number of pathways involved in anaerobic respiration. It's not like the Krebs cycle (TCA) where there's only one pathway in aerobic respiration. To be clear my professional background is carbon fixation. The reason aerobic respiration is important is it can get conflagrated (how do you spell it?) anyway mixed up - with the rTCA (described below) 'cause its the same genes but reverse process. If that happens it’s a disaster :-) because the calculations are kaput.
Anyway, here's a number of examples.
Lactic Acid
Found in: Certainly in mammals, I would suspect its in all vertebrates and some bacteria Lactobacillus is one
Pyruvate is converted to Lactic Acid (C3H5O3) in the absence of oxygen.
Classic fermentation such as making beer, thats yeasts, and some bacteria.
Pyruvate to Ethanol (C2H5OH) + Carbon Dioxide (CO2).
This occurs in brewing and baking processes.
Methanogenesis
Produces methane (CH4) which occurs in methanogen bacteria which include archaea and bacteria in the stomachs of ruminants in the digestion of cellulose from grass. This does occur in the soil in the degradation of living matter and also found in high abundance in peat bogs.
Sulfur reducing bacteria
Produces hydrogen sulfide (H2S) and are found in hydro-thermal vents and thought to be the origin of respiration, not necessarily these bacteria but biochemical process in the first life-forms.

Its important to distinguish this from bacteria that are purely involved in  carbon-fixation e.g. the Arnon-Buchanan cycle - this is the reverse TCA, which is performed mostly by chemolithotrophs, a diverse group of bacteria.   The reason I brought this up is that rTCA - the exact reverse of the Krebs cycle in aerobic respiration, is carbon fixation but not respiration.
Methanogens both fix CO2, i.e. carbon fixation but this is also their pathway of respiration.

As for citations, most of this pretty basic so:
Lactic acid.
Alberts, B., et al. (2014). Molecular Biology of the Cell (6th ed.). Garland Science.
Sulfur reduction and alcohol fermentation
Madigan, M. T., et al (2020). Brock Biology of Microorganisms (16th ed.). Pearson.
For methanogenesis (what I know most about):
Thauer, R. K., and Shima, S. (2008). "Methane as Fuel for Anaerobic Microorganisms." Annual Review of Microbiology, 62(1), 43–64.

Final point, just waving my arms about a bit, I'd suggest the diversity of anaerobic respiration infers one of these was the ancestral pathway of respiration (it's a hot topic).

Hans Adolf Krebs, Nobel laureate.
